# Failure of the Steady State Theory

Tags: cosmology, universe

I was reading a journal of astronomy and came to the most famous opponent of Big Bang theory:

> **The Steady State Theory**:
>
> The 20th - century theory was proposed by Hoyle,Gold and Bondie. The theory is based on the [Perfect Cosmological Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_cosmological_principle) which states that universe has no change in its appearance and is homogeneous. It is isotropic in nature. When an old star dies,new star replaces it. So everything remains the same . According to the theory, the universe has neither any beginning nor any end. Universe was and will always the same through the whole time.

Then I was surprised when the journal wrote that this theory has no scientific existence now. It is obsolete today. While reading this, I have found nothing wrong. Isn't the universe isotropic? Why did the Steady State theory fail?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory) says the discovery of the CMB was the final nail in the coffin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.aip.org/history/cosmology/ideas/bigbang.htm) is a good basic summary of the history of the steady-state theory and the observations that caused it to fall out of favor, mainly the second two mentioned by Kyle Kanos. One of these was the observation of intense radio sources that didn't seem evenly distributed throughout the universe, but were only seen at large distances (higher redshifts):

> The program at Cambridge was led by Martin Ryle, who in 1974 would
>   receive the Nobel Prize in physics for his overall contributions to
>   radio astronomy. In 1951 Ryle believed that radio sources were located
>   within our galaxy, and hence were of no cosmological interest. But
>   over the next few years he became convinced that most of the radio
>   sources he was detecting were extragalactic. His observations, then,
>   could be used to test cosmological models. Ryle argued that his survey
>   of almost 2,000 radio sources, completed in 1955, contradicted
>   steady-state theory, because more distant/older sources seemed to be
>   distributed differently from nearby ones. But he overstated the
>   significance of his initial data. Only after more years of work would
>   radio observations argue strongly against steady-state theory.

And the other was the blackbody spectrum of the cosmic microwave background radiation, which is naturally predicted by the Big Bang theory but not by the steady-state theory (Alpher and Herman had predicted it in the 1940s and the idea had been rediscovered by Robert Dicke and Yakov Zel'dovich in the early 1960s, all before its actual discovery in 1965):

> In 1963 Arno Penzias and Robert Wilson, studying the sky's microwave
>   "noise" for Bell Telephone Laboratories, realized that they had
>   detected microwaves coming from all around the sky, a universal
>   background radiation. Robert Dicke, a physicist nearby at Princeton
>   University, learned of the measurement and in 1965 correctly
>   interpreted it as radiation of about 3 degrees Kelvin, left over from
>   the big bang. Dicke had not known about Alpher and Herman's
>   prediction, and had independently thought of the cosmic background
>   radiation. Even before learning of Penzias and Wilson's observation,
>   Dicke had set his former student James Peebles to work on calculating
>   the nature of this radiation. Only later was Alpher and Herman's
>   predition recovered and appreciated.
>
> ...
>
> The minority who still preferred steady-state theory were not
>   convinced that the big bang had been detected. Couldn't Penzias and
>   Wilson's single observation have some other explanation? Hoyle argued
>   that the radiation could come from interaction between stellar
>   radiation and interstellar needle-shaped grains of iron. Only a number
>   of measurements at different frequencies could confirm that the
>   radiation had the properties predicted for a remnant of the big bang.
>   It was not until the early 1970s that techniques advanced enough to
>   make these measurements, bringing abundant confirmation.
>
> For most purposes, however, the debate between the big bang and the
>   steady state was over in 1965, with big bang the clear winner.
>   Steady-state advocates were reduced to making ad hoc arguments of
>   little plausibility, and they were increasingly marginalized.

[This page](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/stdystat.htm) goes into some more technical detail, and mentions another issue brought up in Godparticle's answer, that of the abundance of helium, which can be explained easily by Big Bang nucleosynthesis but not by the steady-state theory:

> The Big Bang was originally proposed in the context of making all the
>   elements. But the lack of a stable nucleus with atomic weight A=5
>   meant that only isotopes of hydrogen, helium and a trace of lithium
>   are produced in [Big Bang Nucleosynthesis](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/BBNS.html). In the original Steady
>   State proposal, all of the heavy elements were produced in stars by
>   burning hydrogen into helium and then combining several helium nuclei
>   [alpha particles] into heavier nuclei like carbon (3 alpha particles)
>   and oxygen (4 alpha particles). In general the heavy element
>   abundances relative to hydrogen are proportional to each other. Some
>   stars have very little oxygen and these usually also have very little
>   iron, and so on. But helium is definitely an exception to this rule.
>   There is a non-zero floor to the helium abundance as the oxygen
>   abundance goes to zero. This is shown in the plot at right which shows
>   the helium and oxygen abundances relative to hydrogen by number of
>   nuclei in the Sun and several ionized hydrogen nebulae [H II regions]
>   in our Milky Way [M42 is the Orion nebula, M17 is the Omega nebula],
>   in the nearby dwarf galaxies known as the Large and Small Magellanic
>   clouds [LMC and SMC], and in other extragalactic H II regions.
>
> [image]
>
> This plot clearly shows that solid line, which allows for the
>   primordial helium produced in the Big Bang, is a much better fit than
>   the dashed line which is the prediction of the Steady State model with
>   no primordial helium. The data for this plot were taken from Figure 1b
>   of a [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0407176) on the element abundances in the Sun. Shortly
>   before the discovery of the CMB killed the Steady State model, Hoyle &
>   Tayler (1964, Nature, 203, 1008) wrote "The Mystery of the Cosmic
>   Helium Abundance" in which they decided that most of the helium in the
>   Universe was not produced in stars. Hoyle held open the possibility of
>   explosions in supermassive objects instead of a single Big Bang, but
>   ordinary stars were ruled out.

The page also mentions that although Hoyle abandoned the original steady-state model, he continued to advocate a "quasi-steady state cosmology" (QSSC) where the universe continually expands and contracts in an oscillatory way, and the author of the page gives some technical arguments as to why this model still can't adequately account for all the observations that are generally taken to support the Big Bang model.

Comment: "... cosmic microwave background radiation, which is naturally predicted by the Big Bang theory". Quite poorly, though. See [Cosmic Microwave Background in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), [footnote 43](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Apeiron-V2-p79-84%281995%29.pdf). Quote: "... Gamow and collaborators obtained from T » 5 K to T = 50 K ... These are quite poor predictions compared with Guillaume, Eddington, Regener and Nernst, McKellar and Herzberg, Finlay-Freundlich and Max Born, who arrived at, ...

Comment: ... respectively: 5 K < T < 6 K, T = 3.1 K, T = 2.8 K, T = 2.3 K, 1.9 K < T < 6.0 K! All of these authors obtained these values from measurement and or theoretical calculations, but none of them utilized the Big Bang."

Comment: @bright magus - The main point is just that the Big Bang naturally predicts a universal background radiation with a blackbody spectrum, while the steady state has no reason to predict such a thing. It may be that knowledge of early conditions and cosmological parameters wasn't good enough to get a very accurate prediction of the temperature, but that doesn't change the fact that the CMBR confirmed a Big Bang prediction and was inconsistent with SST; those other authors seem to have based their predictions on empirical observations like cosmic rays, not an alternate *model* for producing CMBR.

Comment: "those other authors **seem** to have based their predictions on empirical observations like cosmic rays, not an alternate model for producing CMBR." Is this a fact or you are speculating?

Comment: @bright magus - I was just basing that on having skimmed the [paper you linked to](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Apeiron-V2-p79-84%281995%29.pdf). The estimates by Guillaume & Eddington on p. 79-80 are said to be based based purely on the radiation from stars, the estimate by Regener on p. 80-81 is said to be based on "the density of energy produced by cosmic
rays", Nernst on p. 81 had some kind of aether-based cosmology to explain redshifts but the description makes it sound like his temperature estimate was just building off Regener's work.

Comment: (continued) Herzberg on p. 82 is said to have based his estimate on "cyanogen measurements in interstellar space" made by McKellar, where the fraction of excited molecules was used to derive an equilibrium temperature. Finlay-Freundlich on p. 82 did have a model of sorts, but the model was meant to explain cosmological redshift without the need for universal expansion, he proposed redshift was proportional to the temperature of the radiation field in space but there's no suggestion he proposed any new explanation for the temperature of space other than radiation from stars / cosmic rays.

Comment: 1) Nernst "In 1937 ... developed this **model** and proposed a tired light explanation of the cosmological redshift, namely, the absorption of radiation by the luminiferous ether, decreasing the energy and frequency of galactic light", 2) Finlay-Freundlich "In 1953-4 ... proposed a **tired light model** to explain the redshift of solar lines and some anomalous redshifts of several stars, as well as the cosmological redshift.", "... [they] proposed an alternative to the Doppler interpretation of the cosmological redshift and arrived at 1.9K < T < 6.0K for the temperature of intergalactic space"

Comment: Also, as far as I know, BB had not predicted CMB as residue (BB predictions were about black body radiation and temperature of space). The residue concept appeared as a consequence of Guth's theory of inflation in 1980's, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @bright magus - As I said, Nernst proposed that the redshift was proportional to the temperature of space, and thus worked backwards from the redshift to derive a temperature estimate from this model, but it doesn't seem as if he proposed an actual physical explanation for the temperature of space involving anything other than conventional sources like stars. In any case, tired light models have been [falsified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light#Specific_falsified_models) by later tests.

Comment: @bright magus - And you're incorrect that CMBR requires inflation, the CMBR photons are assumed to have been emitted during the period of "photon decoupling" (closely linked to the [recombination epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)) when the universe cooled down enough for the free electrons in the previously opaque plasma filling space to become bound to protons, forming a transparent gas that photons could pass freely through) about 380,000 years after inflation ended (or after the Big Bang itself, in pre-inflationary versions of the Big Bang theory).

Comment: "[Nernst] worked backwards from the redshift to derive a temperature estimate from this model," Perhaps. Now, was this explanation: "the CMBR photons are assumed to have been emitted during the period of 'photon decoupling' " proposed before or after Penzias' discovery? (I don't mean to argue about the primacy of any of the theories. All I'm saying is that BB rather explained CMB after the discovery than correctly predicted it as an element of its current version. BB predicted a phenomenon, but it's value and role in the theory seriously changed after the discovery, didn't it?)

Comment: [This paper on the history](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2146.pdf) indicates that the basic idea that the very early universe was radiation-dominated, and that some of this radiation would linger today and contribute to the temperature of space, had been proposed by 1948. However, p. 129 of *The Physics of the Cosmic Microwave Background* [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=J2KCisZsWZ0C&lpg=PA93&pg=PA129) indicates that the specific notion of the universe transitioning suddenly from an opaque plasma to a transparent state wasn't proposed until 1968.

Comment: By 1948 you mean Gamov? Yes, I mentioned him in the very first comment I made here to your answer. (Curiously, the Nobel was awarded to the guys who found what they thought was noise, and not to the guys who predicted it as a pillar of a grand theory ...)

Comment: @bright magus - Yes, Gamow, and also Alpher and Herman, according to the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2146.pdf) I linked to there was a flurry of work by all of them in 1948 developing new ideas about the consequences of a "hot Big Bang" model (as opposed to an alternative I'd never heard of, the "cold Big Bang" model).

Answer (score 4):

The steady state theory fails to model a few **observed** features of the universe:

- the accelerated [expansion of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_universe)
- [radio galaxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_galaxy) and [quasars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) that are only observed at high [redshifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) & not everywhere
- the existence of the [microwave background light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background)

Comment: Sir isn't the universe homogeneous and isotrophic?

Comment: @user36790: On large enough scales, yes. But I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user36790: Homogeneous and isotropic means that the laws of the physics in the universe behave the same everywhere, not that it looks identical from all vantage points (which is what it seems you are attributing to it).

Comment: Hmmm... It is awkward to say universe has no beginning. So is not the Perfect Cosmological Principle a wrong then???

Comment: @user36790: Yes, the Perfect Cosmological Principle, which is more-or-less the backbone of the failed Steady-State model is incorrect.

Comment: @user36790 - homogenous and isotropic refer to what the universe is like at different points in space at a single moment of cosmological time, they don't preclude the universe changing significantly over time (so that more distant regions appear *visually* different from closer regions, due to longer light delays), as the "Perfect Cosmological Principle" would.

Comment: @user36790 Before we settled on the Big Bang, "homogeneous" and "isotropic" would probably be interpreted as you're thinking - homogeneous and isotropic in spacetime. Once we decided the universe was *not* in steady state, we started implicitly restricting these terms to mean *spatially* homogeneous and *spatially* isotropic. People simply got tired of saying "spatially" everywhere, so they omitted it.

Answer (score 2):

The following passage has been extracted from the book Parallel worlds:

> Finally, in Nature magazine in 1965, Hoyle officially conceded defeat,
>   citing the microwave background and helium abundance as reasons
>   for abandoning his steady state theory.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem for steady state theory now would be  bow can steady state theory produce dark matter and baryonic matter?
That is a big problem for the theory.It would be hard to find a conservation law for this process.