# The steady state theory, can it now be falsified on particle physics grounds, in addition to CMB data?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background, steady-state

The steady state theory is no longer taken seriously by most physicists and the Big Bang theory is supported by an enormous amount of evidence, especially the CMB data.

But from a quick scan through Wikipedia [Steady State Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_State_theory), and also an answer on this site, [Failure of the Steady State Model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142724/), the evidence seems to be based on supporting the Big Bang model, (and that is understandable in hindsight), rather than any direct falsification of the steady state hypotheses.

My questions are:

- Did Hoyle et alia,  ever actually propose a mechanism for the occurrence (to put it crudely) of the odd particle pair popping up here and there from the vacuum across the universe, which is possibly no more or less likely, or easier to explain, than the origin of the Big Bang event? I am very far out of my depth on this aspect but please bear with me.
- If they did propose a model, could it actually be occurring or have we learned so much more now since the 1940 - 50 era that we can discount the steady  state idea on today on particle physics grounds in addition to the cosmological ones we currently use?

Comment: Even if such a model had been proposed, it would be completely falsified at this time... unless we assume that Hoyle et al. had intellectual superpowers and could predict more than half a century of particle physics data? In other words, one can only be wrong once, after that one stays wrong. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne so they just handwaved, mainly on the fact they had preconceived ideas, based around an isotropic, homogeneous eternal universe  and at that time there was nothing much to support the then mad big bang idea? Like lots of physics, it's mad then it's mainstream. I just never read of any proposal they made to explain the production, other than "it's happens because, well the existing stuff is here". Just curious did anybody press them on it, although I grant that it's a history topic now.

Comment: Curiously, the only thing that Hoyle was fundamentally wrong about was WHAT the universe keeps generating. He though that it had to generate new matter... in reality it generates something far more important: spacetime, which eventually may turn into a brand new universe. He was so close to being a scientific genius... if he had just pushed the idea one or two steps further he would have been ahead of everyone...

Comment: "The existing stuff is here" is simply the definition of science, so that's OK. Where the difficulty with cosmology arises is the often pronounced lack of imagination what "being here" actually means on a cosmological scale. Most people, I think Hoyle included, have a very anthropocentric idea about "existence". Once we give that up and we accept that our scale and our oder parameters are completely irrelevant to the long term dynamic then the creation problem disappears entirely IMHO, but so does our ability to see the deep past and the deep future and that is humbling beyond belief.

Comment: @CuriousOne Agreed,  He was sharp as a tack and on a TV interview he said he would never get anywhere unless he went up against the consensus...so there was lots of politics involved in his career and no  trip to Sweden for his carbon stellar synthesis work.  He was born not 100 miles away from me, and Yorkshire people are renowned for going their own way...

Comment: Sadly, what Hoyle seems to have lacked in his defiance was the willingness to subjugate himself to the only true force... nature. It's OK to go against the grain of your wooden colleagues, it's a disaster if one does it against facts.